# Render key as html property in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and need to render meta tag with non-standard properties.

```
<meta name="some-name" key="some-key" values="some,values">
```

Since `key` property is special in React, React won't propagate it to children and it won't render it. How can I work around this? I know React will pass any unknown property to HTML tag but I can't use `data-key` (for example), I need to render `key` property specifically.

I'm using [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and don't have control over head element therefore I can't do

```
<head dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<meta key="value">'}}></head>
```

I also can't use React refs because I'm rendering this on server-side (and client-side) and doesn't have access to components lifecycle nor reference to DOM element.

EDIT: I modified original answer to exclude any reference to Typescript because question is about React, not Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work for me:

```
const someMeta = {
    "data-one": "one",
    "data-two": 2
};

<div {...someMeta} >text</div>
```

if you need `key` in response from server render for example, you can try `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

my example:
[image]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebVzZm

Comment: That doesn't even answer my question. Html would be `<div data-one="one" data-two="2">text</div>` in your case. I want to render `<div key="data">text</div>`.

Comment: innerHTML can't set properties, only inner HTML

Comment: Now please try it with meta tags and without control over `head` tag. Your solution is basically `<head dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<meta key="value">'}}></head>` which I sadly can't do :( This is why I orignally said you are not answering my question. Try to answer it specifically for `meta` tag, please

Comment: for this i think well be good https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

Comment: Exactly, I'm using React Helmet, that's why I don't have control over head

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the following, in your doctype declaration, you can add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[
  <!ATTLIST tag myAttri CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Where `myAttri` is your attribute, you can name it `key` to match what you want.

`#IMPLIED` means that it's optional. If you want it on every single element, you can use `#REQUIRED`

You can also try setting the attribute through js with

`document.getElementById("foo").myAttri = "myVal"`

Comment: I wish to keep my doctype declaration as it is, HTML5

Comment: @DreadBoy The only way to add custom attributes is through altering the `DTD` or using `data-*`

You can not achieve what you want in any other way.

Comment: @DreadBoy I have edited my answer with another thing you can try.

Comment: To answer 1st comment: I don't care if HTML isn't valid, browsers will handle it. I don't see a point in changing doctype definition because `key` is rejected by React, not browsers. 2nd comment: I'm rendering this on server-side and I don't have reference to `<meta>` element :(

Comment: @DreadBoy Maybe you can use refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html to add the attribute through javascript in that case.

Comment: I also can't, it's server-side app :(

Comment: @DreadBoy Damn, have you checked out some type of solution similar to this? https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/